# Unable to increase db sessions count

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently I've 784 session counts on oracle db and want to increase it hence executed query with sysdba -

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET sessions=1248 SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

and when I tried to check session counts with following, it still shows 784 -

```
SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions';
```

Please help to understand why sessions count is not increased.

Comment: Have you shutdown and restarted the database? `sessions` is not [a modifiable parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams234.htm#REFRN10197) so it cannot be changed on the fly.

Comment: Yes, you're right after shutdown and restart the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the spfile changes initialization settings for the next time you restart the database. v$parameter shows the currently valid set of initialization settings, from the *last* time you restarted, or for anything modified with "scope=memory" or "scope=both".